# Am I interpreting antiderivatives the right way?

Tags: integration

[image]

Here the antiderivative of $f(x)=x^2$ is $F(x) = x^3/3 + C$. If the constant of integration is $C = 0$, then for any $x$, $F(x)$ would give me the area under the curve of $f(x)$ from $0$ till $x$ since $F(0) = 0$. Is this correct? If it is, then for $x<0$ why is $F(x)$ giving a negative value?
Also, what would $F(x) = x^3/3 + 0.5$ represent? The area of $f(x)$ from what seems to be $-1.2$ to $x$?

Comment: I would edit out the tabs next time I posted an image :P

Comment: Fuck, I didn't notice that :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is kind of correct.

$F(x)$ would give you the area between $0$ and $x$, counted positively if $x>0$ since you're going forward from $0$ to $x$, and counted negatively if $x<0$ since you're going backward from $0$ to $x$.

$F(x)=x^3/3+0.5$ gives you the area between $\alpha:=-\sqrt[3]{1.5}$ and $x$, because $F(\alpha)=0$.

Comment: Why is area counted negatively when going backwards from 0 to x? How can area be negative? Also, in this case, if I plug in, say $x=2$ in $F(x) = x^3/3 + 0.5$, would that give me the (area from 0 to 2) - (the area from $-\sqrt[3]{1.5}$ to 0)? If this is true, why does the $F(x)$ graph give a higher value for $x = 2$ if $C = 0.5$? If areas are being subtracted, shouldn't its value be lower at $x = 2$?

Comment: Well an integral computes an arbitrary area, which means that it could have either a positive or a negative value. Depending on whether it's above or beside the x-axis, and whether you're counting forward or backward.

Comment: In your example, it would give you the area between $-\sqrt[3]{1.5}$ and $2$. It gives you a higher value because you're counting much more area since you also count the area from $-\sqrt[3]{1.5}$ to $0$ in addition to the area from $0$ to $2$.

Comment: But wouldn't the area from $-\sqrt[3]{1.5}$ be negative(as you previously stated)? In that case adding the negative area would decrease the value of $F(x)$ at $2$

Comment: No it would be positive, because you're counting from $-\sqrt[3]{1.5}$ to the right so you count positively, also the area you're counting is above the x-axis, so you're counting it positively.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to emphasize the difference between integrals and antiderivatives.

An antiderivative of a function $f : I \to \mathbb{R}$ (where $I$ is any open subset of $\mathbb{R}$) is **any** function $F : I \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $F'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in I$. Clearly, is $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$, then so is $F + C$ for any constant $C \in \mathbb{R}$, since the derivative of a constant function is $0$. If $I$ is an open interval, then it follows from the [Lagrange mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) that any two antiderivatives of $f$ can only differ by a constant. We often write
$$
\int f(x)dx = F + C
$$
to indicate that all antiderivatives of $f$ can be written as $F + C$ for some constant $C$.

A (definite) [integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral) of a function $f$ over an interval $[a, b]$ has a more technical definition. It can be interpreted as the signed surface area between the $x$-axis, the curve and the endpoints $a$ and $b$. By signed I mean that the area bellow the $x$-axis counts negatively. The definite integral of $f$ from $a$ to $b$ is denoted as
$$
\int_a^b f(x)dx
$$
and the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) says that, under some conditions on $f$,
$$
\int_a^b f(x)dx = F(b) - F(a)
$$
for any antiderivative $F$ of $f$. If you're interested in the positive area between curve, $x$-axis and endpoints, you should calculate
$$
\int_a^b \lvert f(x)\rvert dx.
$$

In your example, since $x^2$ is already a positive function, the area between $x$-axis, curve and the (vertical lines through) the endpoints $a < b$ of an interval is given by
$$
\int_a^b x^2dx = \frac{b^3}{3} - \frac{a^3}{3}
$$
which is always positive, assuming $a < b$.

Comment: Further to Bib-lost's nice answer, I would like to recommend the essay "Differential Forms and Integration" by Terrence Tao: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/preprints/forms.pdf
He explains the differences, and relations between the 3 types of integral encountered in single-variable calculus. In my opinion his explanation is as clear as could possibly be, given the inherent complexity of the subject matter. It might be a hard read, but for all the right reasons !